# Cron log on debian systems

Tags: logs, cron

On Redhat systems cron logs into `/var/log/cron` file. What is the equivalent of that file on Debian systems?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Under Ubuntu, `cron` writes logs via `rsyslogd` to `/var/log/syslog`. You can redirect messages from `cron` to another file by uncommenting one line in  `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`. I believe, the same applies to Debian.

Answer (score 8):

Debian has the default rsyslog.conf under `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and the cron line is in default file on line 63

Edit:

Good point by Anthony Geoghegan.

Version of my debian is 9 I'm not sure how it is in previous versions

```
 54 ###############
 55 #### RULES ####
 56 ###############
 57 
 58 #
 59 # First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
 60 #
 61 auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
 62 *.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
 63 cron.*                          /var/log/cron.log
 64 daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
 65 kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
 66 lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
 67 mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
 68 user.*                          -/var/log/user.log
```

Comment: This answer would be a lot more useful if you included line 63 into your answer (and mention which version/release of Debian this applies to).

Answer (score 4):

On Debian 10 (buster) I couldn't find `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` file. I had to edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and remove comment on 63rd line.